# Changing div display on click using css dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, the parentAppliance is part of main left nav table and on hovering over "Appliance" I see a subtable containing "health". Now I want the subtable to disappear when I click on "Health", any thoughts?

CSS:

```
.childAppliance
    {
        display:none;
    }
.parentAppliance:hover .childAppliance
    {
        display: block;
        top: 50px;
        left: 130px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Appliance" id="ui-id-83" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" title="" data-original-title="">
    <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span><ins class="ui-navigation-static-menu-icon ui-navigation-static-menu-icon-backup"></ins>
    <span class="ui-navigation-static-menu-text" style="display: inline;">Appliance</span>
</a>
<ul id="ApplianceSubTable" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all childAppliance" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-83">
    <li itemid="Health" class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Health" id="ui-id-33" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus applianceFocus" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" title="">
            <span class="ui-navigation-static-menu-text">Health</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To actually toggle states persistently you'll need Javascript.

Comment: -1 Please do not post the same question twice. Alter your first one to provide more details or remove it before posting again.

Comment: Please don't re-post just because you didn't get an answer you like the first time.

Comment: You don't have a `parentAppliance` in your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript/Jquery for that.

HTML

```
<li itemid="Health" class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation" id="Health">
```

jQuery

```
$( "#Health" ).click(function() {
  $('#ApplianceSubTable').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some javascript adding a `clicked` class.

```
$('.parentAppliance').on('click', function () { $(this).toggleClass('clicked'); });
```

And the css

```
.parentAppliance.clicked .childAppliance { 
display: block;
top: 50px;
left: 130px;
}
```

Using javascript you can toggle a class which behaves like a hover.